# Do cosmological event horizon evaporates like black-hole horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, event-horizon, cosmological-inflation, hawking-radiation

While the inflation phase of the universe, expansion was exponential and so the universe was de Sitter-like. So, for a point-like observer, there was a cosmological event horizon. Do this horizon evaporates due to the emission of particles? If this horizon evaporates does this mean that the expansion tends to be naturally not in a de Sitter phase?

Edit:

What I've tried so far:

The temperature of the de Sitter horizon is:
\begin{equation}
T=\frac{H}{2\pi}.
\end{equation}
Where $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$. The area of the horizon is:
\begin{equation}
A=\frac{4\pi}{H^2}.
\end{equation}
I don't know if I can do this but let's say that the luminosity inside de horizon due to Hawking radiations is $L=\sigma A T^4$, where $\sigma$ is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant. Assuming that the energy associated to the Horizon is $E_\text{dS}=\alpha H^2$ ($\alpha$ is a proportionality constant), we thus have :
\begin{equation}
\frac{d H^2}{dt}=-\frac{2\sigma}{\alpha (2\pi)^3}H^2.
\end{equation}
Whose solution is:
\begin{equation}
H(t)=H(0)e^{-\frac{\sigma}{\alpha (2\pi)^3}t}
\end{equation}
Then, we find an $a$ of the following form:
\begin{equation}
a(t)=C\,\text{exp}\left( -\frac{\alpha (2\pi)^3}{\sigma}H(0)e^{-\frac{\sigma}{\alpha (2\pi)^3}t} \right)
\end{equation}
Which tends to $0$ at $t\rightarrow-\infty$, is exponential when $t\sim0$, and tends to give a Minkowski-like metric for $t\rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: This discusses event horizons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Cosmic_event_horizon .  I think you are confusing the Big Bang universe with a black hole event horizon ?

Comment: No I don't, these horizons come from different contexts (even though the Schwatzschild-de Sitter metric exists). I was thinking about the Gibbons-Hawking effect and the particle creation by a de Sitter horizon. Since those particles are created inside the horizon, in opposition to particles created by black holes, I thought that the energy associated to the horizon was increasing with time. So the radius of horizon should increase with time too, thus the expansion tends to not be in a de Sitter phase. But I am not sure about this.

Comment: sorry, it is not my field,so I cannot help you.

Comment: Hi Jeanbaptiste Roux@ I am very much confused about your usage: "inflation phase . . . cosmological event horizon". You seem to be saying that none of several definitions of a "cosmological event horizon" presented in the Wikipedia article match what you mean with respect to your question. It would be very helpful if you would post a reference to a specific definition which you have in mind. The Schwatzschild-de Sitter metric does not apply to cosmological inflation.

Comment: I know that the de Schwarzschild-de Sitter metric does not apply to cosmological inflation. But I think de Sitter's does since inflation is conjectured to be an exponential expansion. This is why I used "cosmological event horizon" though I have to admit this is not a good naming. I meant by this a causal event horizon arising from this de Sitter phase. The radius of this event horizon should have been very small because of the very fast expansion of the universe in the inflation epoch.

Comment: Hi @Jeanbaptiste Roux . I am guessing that (1) your view of the universe is finite and hyper-spherical based on the de Sitter metric, and (2) it is expanding exponentially.  I still fail to understand your view of the horizon. There are two general possibilities. (a) An observer looks backward in time as far as possible, like the radius of the observable universe at which the sphere of observation (the horizon) is receding at the speed  of light. (b) Several alternatives described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon .

Comment: Hi @Buzz and thank you for your comments. I was probably unclear in my explanations, sorry about that. I don't think the universe is hyperspherical. What I said is that for a point observer, in a de Sitter universe, there is an event horizon, as described by the so-called de Sitter metric. I think every point of a de Sitter space sees its own horizon because every point can be used as the origin of the referential of the de Sitter metric. I don't think the universe is expanding exponentially, I think that in the inflation phase, it was.

Comment: Hi @Jeanbaptiste Roux . I am still not sure of your horizon concept. In the article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter%E2%80%93Schwarzschild_metric#Horizon_properties there is this section about different horizon concepts. Which one is the one your question is talking about?

Comment: Hi @Buzz. According to this article, it would be a past horizon, though it is claimed that past and future horizons are physically the same. I guess that it implies the Gibbons-Hawking effect, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Hi @Jeanbaptiste Roux . I think I now understand what you are asking. You want to know whether a horizon such as a sphere of a radius moving away from a hypothetical observer during inflation at a speed greater than the speed of light (like the boundary of an observable universe) has the quality of Hawking radiation speculated for the event horizon of a black hole. Is this correct?

Comment: Hi @Buzz It is correct but the event horizon I'm talking about is the one of the de Sitter metric : $ds^2=\left( 1- \frac{r^2}{l^2} \right)dt^2-\left( 1- \frac{r^2}{l^2} \right)^{-1}dr^2-r^2 d\Omega^2$, which is "static" in first approximation. I've edited my question so maybe this edit will help you to understand what I am asking

Comment: Hi @Jeanbaptiste Roux . As I understand the metric and its horizon, we are not talking about any kind of realistic model for the universe. As I understand such models, the universe is homogeneous, but the metric is spherically symmetric. The fact the metric has exponential expansion does not make it a homogeneous model, even for inflation.

Comment: @Buzz It is interesting that your understanding is different than mine. For me, this metric describes how a point-like observer will see an exponentially expanding universe, making it directly spherically symmetric by isotropism. This is just a choice of coordinates, and this choice is a local one, whatever the global shape of the universe is.

Comment: Hi @Jeanbaptiste Roux . The metric has variability with respect to radius. At every value of radius, the sphere of that radius is identical for all points in the sphere. This is not isotropic. Isotropy is uniformity in all orientations, but only with respect to a single origin point. If you choose a different origin, it will not be isotropic with respect to that origin. A universe model needs to  homogeneous, and isotropic with respect to just a single origin is not.

Comment: I ran out of edit time. I meant to say: "This is not homogeneous."

Comment: @Buzz As I said it is just a choice of coordinates, de Sitter space is known to well describe the universe at the inflation epoch and our far future as described in the introduction [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_space) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_universe). Moreover, the de Sitter metric I gave is valid for all point-like observers in the universe: they will all see the same expansion and will have their own event horizon.

Comment: Hi @Jeanbaptiste Roux .  I did a quick look at some Wikipedia articles and I think that I have found the basis of some confusion. The de Sitter universe model is NOT based on the de Sitter metric. It is based on a ΛCDM model with only the Λ term non-zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Sitter_universe

Comment: Hi @Buzz, I thought about this possible confusion until I read "There are ways to cast de Sitter space with static coordinates (see de Sitter space), so unlike other FLRW models, de Sitter space can be thought of as a static solution to Einstein's equations even though the geodesics followed by observers necessarily diverge as expected from the expansion of physical spatial dimensions." from your article. Moreover, it is possible to express the de Sitter metric into an FLRW form, according to Wikipedia, once again

Comment: Hi @Jeanbaptiste Roux . I apologize for my confusion. I am not sufficiently familiar with de Sitter space to understand the implications about its horizon.

Comment: @Buzz It was an interesting discussion, I got confused at some moments but it is ok now. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1):

The observable universe, under eternal inflation from dark energy, will asymptotically evolve to a de Sitter spacetime.  This spacetime is a vacuum configuration with a cosmological constant $\Lambda$.  The stationary metric for this spacetime is
$$
ds^2~=~Adt^2~-~A(r)^{-1}dr^2~-~r^2d\Omega^2,~ A(r)~=~(1~-~\Lambda
r^2/3)
$$
A radial null geodesic with $ds^2~=~0$ and $d\Omega^2~=~0$ gives the velocity ${\dot r}~=~dr/dt$ $=~A(r)$, where this pertains to both out and in going geodesics near the cosmological horizon $r~=~\sqrt{3/\Lambda}$ as measured from $r~=~0$.  The total action
for the motion of a particle is $S~=~\int p_r dr$ $-~\int Hdt$. Consider the bare action of massless particles, using methods found in [1], across the horizon from $r$ to $r'$,
$$
S~=~\int_r^{r'}p_rdr~=~\int_r^{r'}\int_0^{p_r}dp_rdr.
$$
The radial velocity of a particle is ${\dot r}~=~dr/dt$ $=~dH/dp_r$, which enters into the action as,
$$
S~=\int_r^{r'}\int_0^H{{dH'}\over{\dot r}}dr.
$$
The field defines $H^\prime~=~\hbar\omega'$.  The integration over frequencies is from $E$ to $E~-~\omega$, for the ADM energy.  The action is properly written as
$$
S~=~-\hbar\int_r^{r'}\int_E^{E-\omega}{{d\omega'}\over{\dot r}}dr,
$$
where the negative sign indicates the quanta is tunneling across the horizon to escape the Hubble region with radius  The radial velocity
$$
{\dot r}~=~\sqrt{\Lambda/3}r
$$
defines the action
$$
S~=~-\hbar\int_r^{r'}\int_0^\omega{{d\omega dr}\over{\pm 1~-~\sqrt{\Lambda r^2/3}
}}~=~\sqrt{3/\Lambda}tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{\Lambda/3}r)
$$
The action is then the delay coordinate evaluated as
$$
r^*~=~\int {{dr}\over{1~-~\Lambda
r^2/3}}~=~\sqrt{3/\Lambda}tanh^{-1}(\sqrt{\lambda/3}r).
$$
The domain $[0,~\sqrt{3/\Lambda})$ defines a real valued action. Since, $tanh^{-1}(x)~=~{1\over 2}ln((1~+~x)/(1~-~x))$ for $r~>~\sqrt{3/\Lambda}$ the argument of the logarithm is negative. In this case the action is
$$
S~=~\sqrt{3/\Lambda}ln\Big({{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}r~+~1}\over{\sqrt{\Lambda/3}r~-~1
}}\Big)~+~i\pi\sqrt{3/\Lambda}.
$$
The imaginary part represents the action for the quantum field emission as $r~\rightarrow~\infty$.  The delay coordinate is defined on $[0,~\infty)$ which assures an S-matrix is defined on an unbounded causal domain, and this holds in general as well.
\vskip.12in The metric elements we need to be concerned about is then $g_{tt}~=~(1~-~\Lambda r^2/3)$, $g_{rr}~=~1/(1~-~\Lambda
r^2/3)$.  The extrinsic tensor (Gauss' second fundamental form) is then $K_{ab}~=~{1\over 2} n^c\partial_c(g_{ab})$, for $n^r~=~\sqrt{A(r)}$.  These are rather easy to evaluate this
$$
K_{tt}~=~n^r\partial_rg_{tt}~=~  {2\over 3}{{\Lambda r}\over
3}(1~-~\Lambda r^2/3)^{1/2}
$$
$$
K_{rr}~=~n^r\partial_rg_{rr}~=~- {2\over3}{{\Lambda r}\over
3}(1~-~\Lambda r^2/3)^{-3/2}.
$$
The curvature $G^{00}~=~(Tr K)^2~-~Tr(K^2)$ which is then
$$
G^{00}~=~(K_{tt}~+~K_{rr})^2~-~K_{tt}^2~-~K_{rr}^2~=~2K_{tt}K_{rr}~=~{8\over
9}\Big({{\Lambda^2 r^2}\over{1~-~\Lambda r^2/3}}\Big).
$$
This is the vacuum energy available in the de Sitter vacuum.
\vskip.12in We now perform a similar analysis above, but instead consider the radiation production according to the transition $\Lambda~\rightarrow~\Lambda~+~\delta\Lambda$.  The transition is considered according to the metric back reaction of the de Sitter vacuum.  This tunneling defines the imaginary part of the action
$$
S~=~\int_{\Lambda_0}^{\Lambda}pdr.
$$
The velocity term here is the computed from the Hamilton equation ${\dot r}~=~\partial H/\partial p$ which permits this to be
written as
$$
S~=~\int_{\Lambda_0}^{\Lambda}\int_0^R{{dr}\over{\dot r}}dH.
$$
The Hamiltonian used is the $H~=~G^{00}$ computed here, with ${\dot r}~=~\pm(1~-~\Lambda r^2/3)$  with
$$
S~=~\int_{\Lambda_0}^{\Lambda}\int_{r_i}^{r_f}dr\Big({{4r}\over
3}\Big)^2\int_{\Lambda_0}^{\Lambda}{\Lambda\over{(1~-~\Lambda
r^2/3)^2}}\Big(1~+~{{\Lambda r^2/3}\over{1~-~\Lambda
r^2/3}}\Big)d\Lambda
$$
$$
=~16\int_{r_i}^{r_f}dr \Big( {1\over{r^2}}\big(log(\Lambda
r^2~-~3)~-~{3\over{\Lambda
r^2~-~3}}\big)\Big|_{\Lambda_0}^{\Lambda}
$$
$$
=~16\big(ln(\Lambda
r^2~-~3)/r~-\sqrt{\Lambda/3}~arctanh(\sqrt{\Lambda/3}r)~-~1/r\big)
\Big|_{\Lambda_0}^{\Lambda}\Big|_{r_i}^{r_f}.
$$
This complicated expression is evaluated for $\Lambda~=~\Lambda_0~-~\delta\Lambda$ with
$$
S~=~8\Big(\sqrt{\Lambda/3}~arctanh({\Lambda/3}r)~+~{r\over{1~-~3/(\Lambda
r^2)}}~+~{2\over{\Lambda~-~3/
r^2}}\Big)\Big|_{r_i}^{r_f}\Delta\Lambda
$$
Of course this solution exhibits a singularity for the radius extended across $\sqrt{3/\Lambda}$.  We then consider the integration with respect to the small change in the cosmological constant
$$
S~=~=~16\int_{r_i}^{r_f}dr \Big( {1\over{r^2}}\Big(log(\Lambda
r^2~-~3)~-~{3\over{\Lambda
r^2~-~3}}\Big)\Big|_{\Lambda_0}^{\Lambda}
$$
$$
\simeq~16\Big({1\over{\Lambda r^2~-~3}}~-~{3\over{(\Lambda
r^2~-~3)^2}}\Big)\delta\Lambda
$$
The calculus of residues and Cauchy integral formula gives this result in a very simple form for $z^2~=~\Lambda r^2$ and we then left with the result
$$
S~=~{\sqrt{3}\over 4}\pi\delta\Lambda
$$
\vskip.12in Now that we have that set up we propose a quantum model.  The $G^{00}~=~H$ which under the Hamiltonian constraint is zero.  Yet with quantum mechanics we propose an evolution equation $i\partial\Psi[g,\phi]/\partial t~=~G^{00}\Psi[g,\phi]$, where the
deviation from zero in the Wheeler DeWitt equation $NH\Psi[g]~=~0$ is due to the occurrence of a scalar field in the spacetime.  For now on we will substitute $H$ for $G^{00}$.  Now we want to compute a transition rate, which involves both a change in g and
the internal scalar field $\phi$.  So we take a second derivative of $\Psi~=~\Psi[g,\phi]$ to get
$$
-{{\partial^2\Psi}\over{\partial t^2}}~=~ H^2\Psi~+~i{{\partial
H}\over{\partial t}}\Psi.
$$
We now express this according to $|\Psi\rangle$ and $\Psi'\rangle$
by
$$
H^2?~=~H\int d\mu(\Psi')|\Psi'\rangle\langle\Psi'|H|\Psi\rangle,
$$
which is just a completeness sum $1~=~\int d\mu(\Psi')|\Psi'\rangle\langle\Psi'|$ inserted between the two Hamiltonians.  We then have a summation over transition probabilities as
$$
\int
d\mu(\Psi')|\langle\Psi'|H|\Psi\rangle|^2~=~-\langle\Psi|{{\partial^2}\over{\partial
t^2}}|\Psi\rangle~-~i\langle\Psi|{{\partial H}\over{\partial
t}}|\Psi\rangle.
$$
The first term on the right hand side depends only on the transition of the scalar field, which vanishes if the scalar field is initially zero.  The last term will then depend upon
$\partial\Lambda/\partial t$, and may be computed from the $G^{00}$ above.  These two terms represent the long wavelength Hawking-Gibbon radiation produced by the decay of the cosmological constant and the change in Hamiltonian due to the production of this radiation.